# Python: Using regex stored in CSV

Tags: python, regex, csv

I am just testing out a small python script of which I will use part in a larger script. Basically I am trying to lookup a field in a CSV file (where it contains a regex), and use this in a regex test. The reason is (part of a very wierd use-case) and will enable easier maintenance of a CSV file instead of the script. Is there something I am missing with the following....

test.csv:

```
field0,field1,field2
foo,bar,"\d+\.\d+"
bar,foo,"\w+"
```

test.py (extra `print`'s used for testing):

```
import sys
import re
import csv

input = sys.argv[1]
print input

reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv','rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar="\"")
for row in reader:
        print row
        value = row[0]
        print value
        if value in input:
                regex = row[2]
                print regex

                pat = re.compile(regex)
                test = re.match(pat,input)
                out = test.group(1)
                print out
```

If I pass a value like "`foo blah 38902462986.328946239846`" to the script, I would expect this to pick up that it contains `foo` and then use the regex, `\d+\.\d+`, to extract `38902462986.328946239846`. However when I run the script I get the following:

```
foo blah 0920390239.90239029
['field0', 'field1', 'field2']
field0
['foo', 'bar', '\\d+\\.\\d+']
foo
\d+\.\d+
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reg.py", line 19, in <module>
    out = test.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Not sure what's going on really.

P.S Python is a big world and ***still*** learning.

Comment: Your code seems incorrectly idented. If test is None then re.match failed (that's what it returns on failure). And this might be because re.match expects a string as the first parameter, not a compiled pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs `re.match` matches at the beginning of the input string. You need to use `re.search`.  Also, there's no need to compile if you don't reuse them afterwards. Just say `test = re.search(regex, input)`.

In the regular expressions in your example you don't have any capture groups, so `test.group(1)` is going to fail, even if there's a match in the `input`.

```
import sys
import re
import csv

input = 'foo blah 38902462986.328946239846'

reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv','rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar="\"")
for row in reader:
    value = row[0]
    if value in input:
        regex = row[2]
        test = re.search(regex, input)
        print input[test.start():test.end()]
```

Prints:

```
38902462986.328946239846
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, it's probably because I'd used match previously so that stuck in my mind.