# How to import Regex from external file with its original format and without extra escape characters

Tags: python, regex

Hell Everyone,

I would like to request your support in the following question.

I am recently working in a Python script that is looking matches for about 15 sentences using regular expressions, in thousands of files.

The sentences that we will be looking for could be changing through the days/weeks and the script will be given to users with knowledge in regular expressions, but not programmability skills.

Then, in order to make this script more scalable I was looking to save the regexs in a different file where those users can modify the sentences without the necessity to modify the python script.

Example

#### This file would be modify continuously to match different sentences.

--- regex.log ---

```
Th\w*\s+sen\w*
\d{0,3}
```

--- matches.py ---

```
import re

with open("regexs.log", "r") as regexs:
    regex = regexs.readlines()

text = "This sentence"

for reg in regex:
    match = re.search(reg, text)
```

However, this is not working... when the regexs are exported, python is adding extra escape characters to the sentence. For instance, for the two regexs above these are imported as below:

```
"Th\\w*\\s+send\\w*"
"\\d{0,3}"
```

The back slash is duplicated, whereby, the regexs are no longer useful, since they don't longer match the sentences.

Just wondering if there is any way to import those regular expressions in its original state?

Similar operation happens if a store the regular expressions in a list:

```
>>> reg = ["\w+\n"]
>>> reg
['\\w+\n']
```

Regards.

Comment: There is a similar approach used here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933374/python-using-regex-stored-in-csv

Answer (score 0):

```py
regex = regex.readlines()
regex = regex.replace("\\", "\") # <= Add this
```

What this does is say "everywhere there is a `\\` replace it with a `\`. But, if you are doing some other things with the file before it is finalized, you'll want to move `replace` to a more appropriate spot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried replace as below:

```
regex = regex.replace("\\", "\")
```

but it returns:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

It seems python is recognizing the "how to replace" (the second, value in replace function) as double quote symbol due to the escape sequence \" rather than a back slash.